# Trying to calculate total memory usage of multiprocess Python code on Linux

Tags: python, linux, memory, multiprocessing

I'm stuck with a memory usage calculation problem for a Python code I have which is using multiprocessing. The code runs on Linux.

Here is the gist of the problem: I have a parent process which forks off bunch of child processes. The address space of the parent process is pretty much readonly from child process point of view (not explicitly marked as Read-Only). When calculating total memory usage, if I don't include children processes I'm underestimating total usage. If I'm including them, I'm double-counting the read-only memory which is pretty sizable. I'm getting RSS value of the processes involved. Not sure how to cleanly estimate memory usage for this code.

Here is a simple code which shows the issue:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import psutil
import resource
import time

large_arr = []
for i in range(100000000):
    large_arr.append(i)

def run():
    print("Starting!")
    # sleeping to get the RSS size for the process
    time.sleep(5)
    sum_val = 0
    small_local_arr = []
    for i in range(1000):
        small_local_arr.append(i)
        sum_val += small_local_arr[-1]
    for elem in large_arr:
        sum_val += elem
    print("Useless work is done!")

process = mp.Process(target=run, name="random_process")
process.start()

def print_mem_usage():
    rusage_self = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF)
    rusage_children = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)
    process_usage = psutil.Process(process.pid).memory_info().rss / 1000
    print(f"Self {rusage_self.ru_maxrss} KB, Children {rusage_children.ru_maxrss} KB, Process {process_usage} KB")

for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    print_mem_usage()
```

Here is the output that gets printed when running it:

> Self 3969424 KB, Children 3196 KB, Process 4062810.112 KB

While true memory use of child process should be much much smaller than the parent process, it's reporting the size to be very close to the memory consumption of the parent process. htop shows the total size of this code to be around 4GB vs. if relying on this code, total size would be 8GB. So I'm effectively double-counting parent's process address space size.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You should not just request a ready solution. SO is for helping solve specific errors, after you've shown your effort solving them

Comment: " is pretty much readonly from child process point of view (not explicitly marked as Read-Only)" the thing is, whenever you even *reference* a Python object, you are writing to it - to the refeerence count. So in effect, you can rarely ever rely on COW for forked processes unless you are handling primitive buffers wrapped by python objects (e.g. numpy.ndarrays)

Comment: In any case, it isn't exactly clear to me what you are *asking*. Are you asking how to *measure this*? Because I would reach to your OS-specific tools for that probably

Comment: Yeah, how to measure this accurately (not underestimating nor overestimating).

Comment: I know I'm overestimating as I compare against memory usage shown by cgroups, htop, or ps.

Comment: Added a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is knowable in a reliable way.  The memory usage of a process includes its working set, even if a big part of that working set is shared with one or more other processes.  There is no way to measure "pages that are shared".  If the parent and all children but one died, nothing changes in the remaining child, but you would want it to get "credit" for all the pages, as the primary owner.

Comment: @TimRoberts, your point is valid. That said, I still need to do some sort of measurement report having cgroups or htop as my golden standard. Can I get close to those real numbers using pss/uss maybe? Instead of RSS? I'm trying that right now to know if that's a better measurement.

Comment: Can you use a global measurement?  Measure total committed pages before you start, then total committed pages while you are running?  I'm not 100% sure that would work, either.

Comment: I think I can definitely hack into it. Was hoping for a clean solution. Using PSS/USS was also not helpful. When I used USS (and I think @juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned that), it feels like it's still counting the pages that are read from shared datastructures. But from htop numbers I can see it's not copying/double-counting the memory. Maybe I'm reading htop wrong though.

Comment: Again, why are you confident that there are shared data structures? Typically, in Python, that is *not* going to happen unless you go out of your way to make it happen, as explained earlier

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, in my actual code, I'm 100% confident because if I sum up total RSS mem for individual processes, the number overshoots the total available RAM by a good 1.5x factor. In my sample code though, when getting the total RES memory usage (from htop), I see that it's closer to that of the parent process. Not 100% confident that looking at htop is the right thing to do though. Probably a more reliable way is to create cgroups for my sample code and track it's memory consumption to know for sure.